# XAML MaterialDesign DatePicker binding year is always 00001

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

How come I Always get 0001 as year when I bind property Date to a DatePicker control (MaterialDesign)

```
 <DatePicker Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Width="200"
             Language="nl-BE"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             DisplayDate="{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

On my ViewModel:

```
 public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

When I push save the year is Always 0001 even in the DatePicker...  And when you click the calender the today date should be default.

Comment: did you assign anything to `BirthDate`?

Comment: @DanielA.White no it should be empty, its a form to add a new person. I want the  datevalue that is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year of the default value (`DateTime.MinValue`) of a `DateTime` is 0001.

You should set the source property (`BirthDate`) to some other value like for example `DateTime.Now`:

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "SelectedDate" instead of "DisplayDate" property.

```
    <DatePicker Grid.Column = "1"
         Grid.Row = "2"
         Width = "200"
         Language = "nl-BE"
         VerticalAlignment = "Center"
         SelectedDate = "{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Same result, year is 0001

Answer (score 0):

Update your DatePicker definition and bind its SelectedDate property (instead of DisplayDate).